# What does "deliver" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A person on Reddit made a post showing a camera he found embedded in a log while he was splitting it.

A user commented and said:

> Develop the film and deliver!

What does *deliver* mean in this context? I have looked it up in several dictionaries, but couldn't find a definition that's relevant to the context.

Comment: Are you sure "embedded" is right in this context ?...I guess you could post the link...never been on reddit

Comment: The user who made that comment demanded the proof of evidence, "Develop that film, and show us!".

Comment: This is highly ambiguous to me "camera he found embedded in a log while he was splitting it"....what I comprehend by this is -: ......(nothing-:its partly my mistake and partly yours)

Comment: This is the [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/1witrl/found_this_while_splitting_logs/) to the post.

Comment: @DamkerngT. So does *deliver* here then means: *to show something (as a proof of evidence)*?

Comment: @Theo It means: to deliver the photos from the developed film to us (on Reddit).

Comment: I think there's a bit of slang going on here. In this context, _deliver_ can mean, "Show us the proof!" (that is, _PROVE that you really found a working camera in a log, by developing the film_); it can mean, "Show us the pictures!" (that is, _get that film developed, and post the pictures for us – we want to see them!_); it can mean, "Come through for us, don't let us down!" (that is, _now that you've whetted our appetite, please don't disappoint us_). I think there are elements of all three of these, rolled into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the camera that was embedded in the log was an older, film-based camera.  The user who commented is asking the original poster to "take the film out of the found camera, get it developed, and deliver the results (that is, the pictures from the film) to us so that we can see them."

Essentially this is definition 2 from [m-w.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deliver?s=t):

> to give into another's possession or keeping

in that the images from the found camera would be presented to the reddit community.

Comment: How can a camera be embedded in a log ?

Comment: Like this, apparently: http://imgur.com/KwLdLMm

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I think the meaning of deliver in this context is a bit richer than M-W Def #2. I'm thinking of a football player making a penalty kick, with his teammates saying on the sideline, "Come on, _deliver_ for us!" It means, "Make something good happen; don't let us down." (somewhat akin to the idiom [_deliver the goods_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deliver+the+goods?qsrc=2446)). The five-word exclamation leads me in this direction.